# Is there a way to integrate Odysee with Wordpress / Essential Grid?

Tags: video-hosting

I'm trying to add a video carousel/slider using Essential Grid or any plugins similar to it.  For censorship reasons, Youtube and Vimeo have de-platformed my videos before so it's not a good option at all.  How do I get these slider/grid plugins to work with Odysee?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the Slide Anything plugin for Wordpress will work.